# using mtcnn.extract to creating cropped faces but when i am saving the cropped face there are some patches coming

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, face-detection

Below is the code that I am using.

[image: Input: image]
[image: output: cropped face]

but when i am using plt.imshow(face) it is showing me fine

```html
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import json
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

mtcnn = MTCNN(keep_all=True)
resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2', device='cuda').eval()
box, probability, landmark = mtcnn.detect(img, landmarks=True)
img_cropped = mtcnn.extract(img, box, None)

    
    
import os
import cv2

# Save cropped face to folder
def save_cropped_face(face, folder, filename):
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    face = np.transpose(face, (1, 2, 0))
    cv2.imwrite(filepath, face)

save_cropped_face(face, 'temp', filename)
```